# How do I use PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer in the below when the property to be injected is a list

Tags: java, spring

How do I use PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer in the below when the property to be injected is a list. I know how it works with annotations. Need to understand its working with xml.

```
<bean id="attributes" class="com.test.SamlAttributes">
    <property name="groups">
        <list>
            <value>group1</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="attribute">
        <list>
            <value>value3</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Reference http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-collections-list-set-map-and-properties-example/

Comment: what you did is correct.. are you getting any error?

Comment: No error. Just wanted to know how I can populate a list using a property file and PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer.

Comment: Define each property of list as separate properties.

Comment: @Swaraj: And then how do I add them to the applicationContext.xml file? So, lets say I need to increase my list in the property file, I would in that case make changes to applicationContext.xml as well

Comment: Yes. That much i am aware of. If there is other solution.. would like to see that